# Display query response time

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

How can I get the query response time from Neo4j using Spring-data-neo4j?

As in the web interface: "Returned 2 rows in 56 ms."?

Example code:

```
public interface UserRepository extends GraphRepository<User> {

    @Query("MATCH (a:User{name:{0}})-[:Visited]->(b:Settlement) return b")
    List<Settlement> getAllSettlementsVisitedByName(final String name);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, the query response time displayed in the browser is measured by the brower itself, on the client side, so you wouldn't be able to get it from Spring.

You can configure Neo4j to output query response times into a logfile. For reference, see this [previous Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29070085/2061244).

Alternatively, Spring Data might have some way of providing response times. I'm not familiar with Spring Data myself, so I'm not able to provide guidance in that direction.

Comment: Adding to this - SDN 4 does not provide response times